# ms sql group by 2 hours

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, sql-server-2017

i have this ms-sql code below, running on sql server 2017:

```
DECLARE @report_int TABLE
(
  atimestamp DATETIME,
  adate DATE,
  ahour INT,
  intvalue INT,
  attribute CHAR(254),
  total INT
)

INSERT INTO @report_int
SELECT
  el.servertimestamp,
  cast(el.servertimestamp as date) adate,
  (DATEPART(HH,el.servertimestamp)) ahour,
  el.intvalue,
  el.attributes,
  0
FROM
  eventlog el
where
  el.servertimestamp  BETWEEN '6/29/2017'
                  AND DATEADD(dd, +1, '6/29/2019')
  and (attributes LIKE '%N<=>OlympieioIn%' OR attributes LIKE '%N<=>OlympieioOut%')
order by
  el.servertimestamp

DECLARE @report TABLE
(
  adate datetime,
  ahour int,
  came_in bigint,
  gone_out bigint

)

--fill report with dates and hours
INSERT INTO @report (adate, ahour) SELECT DISTINCT adate, ahour FROM @report_int

--reset
UPDATE @report set came_in = 0, gone_out = 0

--update in totals, min and max times
UPDATE @report SET came_in = i.total from
@report r,
(
select adate, ahour, COUNT(*) total
FROM @report_int
WHERE attribute LIKE 'N<=>OlympieioIn'
GROUP BY adate, ahour
) i
WHERE
i.adate = r.adate
and i.ahour = r.ahour

--update out totals
UPDATE @report SET gone_out = i.total from
@report r,
(
SELECT adate, ahour, COUNT(*) total
FROM @report_int
WHERE attribute LIKE 'N<=>OlympieioOut'
GROUP BY adate, ahour
) i
where
i.adate = r.adate
and i.ahour = r.ahour

select
  adate,
  ahour,
  RIGHT('00'+cast(ahour as varchar),2)+':00 - '+RIGHT('00'+cast(ahour+1 as varchar),2)+':00' timeframe,
  came_in,
  gone_out
from
  @report
```

This code shows how many people came in or gone out of a building every day. As you can see, the amount of people who come in and go out, are displayed in an hourly grouping.
Below is a screenshot of the executed code.

[image: Here is the link where you can see the screenshot]

What i want to do is group these data in a 2-hour grouping.For example, the grouping of the 3rd and 4th hour of the executed code above, will be:

**DATE(adate):** 2018-05-12
**Hour(ahour):** 15
**Timeframe:** 15:00-17:00
**came_in:** 0
**gone_out:** 2

Your help will be much appreciated,

thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not handling that  on the front end?  Seems like the kind thing that would be better pushed into a JSON array and sorted in the UI if you're just displaying the data

Comment: @MasonStedman I'm making reports using the i-report software, and as i know, this is the best way to extract the needed data, so i don't think that JSON would be any helpful here.

Comment: I mean in the sense that you could pull the hourly breakdown, and process the bi-hourly\hourly via JS on the frontend vs re-calling the data for every report if they want a different breakdown style.  Don't really know what you're trying to do on the front end so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get a datetime to the last 2 hour slot would be to use:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, YourDateColumn) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, YourDateColumn) % 2), 0)
```

If we then take some (random) sample data, you get the following:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),V.DT) AS DT
    FROM (VALUES('2018-07-04T00:11:32'),('2018-07-04T01:17:12'),('2018-07-04T02:00:01'),('2018-07-04T07:49:59'),('2018-07-04T07:59:58'),('2018-07-04T08:00:00')) V(DT))
SELECT DT, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) % 2), 0) AS DT2h
FROM VTE;
```

Which returns:

```
DT                          DT2h
--------------------------- -----------------------
2018-07-04 00:11:32         2018-07-04 00:00:00.000
2018-07-04 01:17:12         2018-07-04 00:00:00.000
2018-07-04 02:00:01         2018-07-04 02:00:00.000
2018-07-04 07:49:59         2018-07-04 06:00:00.000
2018-07-04 07:59:58         2018-07-04 06:00:00.000
2018-07-04 08:00:00         2018-07-04 08:00:00.000
```

If you wanted a `COUNT` by 2 hour slot:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),V.DT) AS DT
    FROM (VALUES('2018-07-04T00:11:32'),('2018-07-04T01:17:12'),('2018-07-04T02:00:01'),('2018-07-04T07:49:59'),('2018-07-04T07:59:58'),('2018-07-04T08:00:00')) V(DT))
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) % 2), 0) AS DT2h, COUNT(DT) AS C
FROM VTE
GROUP BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, DT) % 2), 0);
```

Which returns:

```
DT2h                    C
----------------------- -----------
2018-07-04 00:00:00.000 2
2018-07-04 02:00:00.000 1
2018-07-04 06:00:00.000 2
2018-07-04 08:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'll work on your advice and i'll let you know if i got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply manually create a timetable and join it.
The timetable would have 24 rows (one for each hour) and could look like this:
hour   hourtimeframe   twohourtimeframe
13     13:00 - 14:00   13:00 - 15:00